# Zoom/Expand part of my Mac's screen

Tags: mac, macos, accessibility, zoom

Is there a way to zoom in/expand/enlarge part of my Mac's screen to fill the entire screen?

Basically, I'm looking for an app that allows you to select a part of the screen and that will then expand that part of the screen all the way to cover the full screen. So if I have a monitor that measures 1366x768 and I select a part of the screen that is 500X300 it will then enlarge that small part to cover the full available screen real estate.

Comment: Doesn't what you describe mean to zoom in like accessibility does?

Comment: sure, if I can find an accessibility tool that does it the way I want it. for example looking at all these https://www.google.dk/search?q=magnifiers+mac&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRmtGrj_3NAhXBDSwKHR2JC-oQ_AUICCgB&biw=960&bih=470 it zooms a portion of the window but I still see all that windows. Lets suppose I have a black box 200 px by 200 px on a screen, I want to select that black box,and only see that black box and nothing surrounding it blowed up to the full size of the screen ( aspect ration kept though)  - is there a magnifier that will do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in zoom feature to zoom in on a part of the screen on your Mac.

(**Note**: these instructions are adapted for El Capitan but also work with Sierra and as far back as Lion, though certain menus/buttons may be labeled differently).

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Navigate to the Accessibility Settings menu
3. Choose `Zoom` from the pane on the left.
4. Enable `Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom`.
5. Enable `Smooth images` (for better quality with images)
6. Enable `Zoom follows the keyboard focus`.
7. Ensure your Zoom settings match these:

[image: Ideal zoom settings]

8. Then, choose between Picture-in-picture and Fullscreen for the `Zoom Style`; **see the pictures below for help choosing.**

**Zoom in `picture-in-picture` mode:**

[image: Picture-in-picture mode]

**Zoom in `fullscreen` mode:**

[image: Fullscreen mode]

After turning on Zoom, you can control it with keyboard shortcuts, as mentioned by Paul Zagoridis:

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> toggles zoom on/off.

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> zooms in.

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> zooms out.

Source + more info: http://basics4mac.com/article.php/magnify

Reply below for any additional help or if you have questions; I hope this helps!

Comment: Is the mouse gesture zoom working for you in Sierra?  It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @wim For me, yep. Try switching the modifier key to just `option`. Here's a video of it working on my MBP running Sierra 10.12.1: https://goo.gl/photos/KcW4ynEmX8gbbmrC8

Comment: Damn, I'm on 10.12.1 and it doesn't work

Comment: @wim try changing the modifier key.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all three choices - no good.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you want a rectangle or circle you'll need to find a screen zoom app.

I just use

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd> to toggle default zoom.

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> to zoom in and

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out.

It centres the zoom on where the mouse is.